# Measuring statistical significance of monthly survey?

Tags: statistical-significance

I have a survey where the same question is asked every month. The survey asks each respondent to give a 1--5 rating, which is then averaged and presented to me.

I have the benchmark average (for the entire pool of respondents), and the average for my group that I care about.

The benchmark average is constant month over month, but my group's average shows a decline.  However, at the same time, the number of responses in my group has increased.

For reference, here's the data:

|  | January | February | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| My group's average | 4.1 | 3.9 | 3.8 |
| My group's # responses | 16 | 20 | 21 |
| Benchmark average | 3.9 | 3.9 | 3.9 |
| Benchmark # responses | >1000 | >1000 | >1000 |

How do I determine whether my group's decline in average is statistically significant?

Comment: (a) Averaging Likert data (essentially ordinal categorical) is controversial. The sample median might be more meaningful. (b) Without knowing the roughly two dozen responses (or at least their variability), I do not see how to do a formal test. (c) With so few responses, it would not be surprising to see month-to-month fluctuations in the mean that are as large as what you have seen--even if opinion has not changed. I will illustrate this in a brief answer using simulation.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose opinion in your group is stable with the following
respective probabilities for Likert-5 responses, which would give mean score $3.8.$

```
op.prop = c(1,1,1,3,4)/10
```

Then let's look at fictitious averages over 1000 months with $n = 20$ responses for your group.

```
set.seed(2021)
a = replicate(1000, mean(sample(1:5, 20, rep=T, p = op.prop)))
summary(a)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.750   3.600   3.800   3.786   4.000   4.600 
sum(a < 3.6 | a>4)
[1] 482
```

The lower and upper quartiles are 3.6 and 4.0,
respectively, so that in about half of the 1000 months, average scores would lie below 3.6 or above 4.0.

With my hypothetical opinion profile for Likert-5 scores in your group
it would not be at all surprising to see month-to-month fluctuations
as large as what you have observed.